# Dynamiclinq library with generic repository

Tags: generics, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern, dynamic-linq

Does anyone have any examples of using the dynamic linq library with a generic repository pattern?

http://nuget.org/packages/DynamicLINQ

http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/19/dynamic-linq-part-2-evolution.aspx

The trouble I'm finding is that dynamicorderby() returns IQueryable, so I can't really use it in a generic repository. And it's cool overriding of orderby e.g. orderby(o => o["mycolumn"]) I can only seem to get working on a concrete implementation.

---

UPDATE:

Here's some sample code, rather than moving it up the stack into the repository, which I'm trying to avoid as the repositories are really clean at the moment, I'm putting it into the business layer (which is ok for the moment).

```
    public IEnumerable<BusinessUnitUser> GetUsers(int pageSize, int pageNumber, out int totalPages, Func<dynamic, dynamic> orderBy, Expression<Func<BusinessUnitUser, bool>> where = null)
    {
        IQueryable<dynamic> dynamicQuery = buUserRepository.Get(pageSize, pageNumber, out totalPages).DynamicOrderBy(orderBy);

        ...
     }
```

And calling it with sometihng like:

```
userBL.GetUsers(gvUser.PageSize, gvUser.PageIndex, out recordCount, o  => o["UserID"])
```

I've put ... as I haven't figuired out how to cast it to IEnumerable yet, but that's not really the problem yet.

The main problem is tat I'm getting an error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[BusinessUnitUser]'
>   to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Object]'.

Which is caused on the .DynamicOrderBy(orderBy);

---

EDIT: Here is the stack trace

> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[EntityLayer.BusinessUnit]'
>   to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Object]'.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1..ctor(InternalContext
>   internalContext, ObjectQuery objectQuery) +170
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.CreateQuery(Expression
>   expression) +116    DynamicLINQ.DynamicQueryable.OrderBy(IQueryable`1
>   source, LambdaExpression expression) +356
>   DynamicLINQ.DynamicQueryable.DynamicOrderBy(IQueryable`1 source,
>   Func`2 selector) +58
>   BusinessLayer.BusinessUnitBL.Get(Int32 pageSize, Int32
>   pageNumber, Int32& totalPages, Func`2 orderBy, Expression`1 where) in
>   C:\TEST\BusinessUnitBL.cs:23
>   UserInterface.Pages.Multitenant.BusinessUnit.DataBindBusinessUnits()
>   in C:\TEST\BusinessUnit.aspx.cs:159
>   UserInterface.Pages.Multitenant.BusinessUnit.SetGridPagerSettings()
>   in C:\TEST\BusinessUnit.aspx.cs:177
>   UserInterface.Pages.Multitenant.BusinessUnit.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) in C:\TEST\BusinessUnit.aspx.cs:49
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2207

Comment: Maybe a solution would be to remove your generic repository if you don't actually need it.

Comment: I'd love to, but we're using the generic repository to inject a multi-tenancy layer / where clause into all queries going through it. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This is a really good reason to use a generic repository! Actually, the first good reason I heard for a long time. Recently, generic repositories have become all the rage for no reason.

Comment: If you could post some sample code that would help a lot.

Comment: A bit off-topic: Do you have success with the new Dynamic LINQ (aside from the gen.repo problem)? Did you already test it a bit? Is it stable? I am using the old Dynamic LINQ in a few projects. I didn't notice that there is something new. Would be interesting to try the new lib for new projects.

Comment: I'm afraid @Slauma, I've only just downloaded it - the API looks pretty cool, but I've not had a chance yet to play with it outside the repository yet. I might right a blog post about it if I can get it working, as there appears to be very little documentation on it at the moment.

Comment: Hi @usr, I'm having a good ol'play with it now, I'll post some sample code once I can get my head around it - thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi @usr I've added a code sample, it's hurting my head! :-)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? What type does buUserRepository.Get return at runtime? In any case, doing the ordering after the paging does not seem right.

Comment: Hi - sorry bit of a bad example, your right about the paging after the sorting, but I've temporarily removed that from the underlying repository - my bad I forgot to remove it from the example. I'll pop on the stack trace when I get back to work, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @usr I've added the stack trace.